# Finding usage of resources (CPU and memory) by threads of a process in unix (solaris/linux)

Tags: linux, multithreading, solaris, cpu-usage

I have a multi-threaded application(C++ and pthread library) and I will like to know how much resources(CPU and memory) each thread uses.
Is there a way to find out these details on Solaris and Linux both or on either of them.

Comment: For linux there's an exact duplicate(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431569/tracking-threads-memory-and-cpu-consumption).

Comment: I checked this out beforehand. My question was also for Solaris. Have not found any thing yet. Only thing i can conclude now is that talking about memory consumption per thread is not a good idea as they share the same memory space. May be we can only calculate what memory was allocated or deallocated by a thread (How to do this ??).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the ps command with some option:

```
ps -eLo pid,ppid,lwp,nlwp,osz,rss,ruser,pcpu,stime,etime,args | more
  PID  PPID    LWP NLWP   SZ  RSS    RUSER %CPU    STIME     ELAPSED COMMAND
    0     0      1    1    0    0     root  0.0   Oct_02  4-02:13:37 sched
    1     0      1    1  298  528     root  0.0   Oct_02  4-02:13:36 /sbin/init
    2     0      1    1    0    0     root  0.0   Oct_02  4-02:13:36 pageout
```

Have a look at the ps man's page to get some information (LWP (light weight process))

Comment: Is LWP a thread? I mean in Linux/Solaris terms. Since in what you have pasted here PPID is 0, I suppose that its a process and not a thread. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes.  LWP is a thread.  http://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/What_is_NLWP_on_Solaris%3F

Comment: As far as i can tell - the pcpu flag gives CPU usage for the process, not for the LWP.